# How to get Http[F] out of the context F?

Tags: scala, servlets, scala-cats, http4s

I am trying to run my webapp that is based on [http4s](https://http4s.org/) on jetty. The http4s library provides [AsyncHttp4sServlet[IO]](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/master/servlet/src/main/scala/org/http4s/servlet/AsyncHttp4sServlet.scala) class to extend and I use as follows:

```
class UserSvcServlet
    extends AsyncHttp4sServlet[IO](
      service = UserSvcServer.start,
      servletIo = BlockingServletIo(4096, Blocker.liftExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())),
      serviceErrorHandler = DefaultServiceErrorHandler
    )
```

As you can see on the `service` property, I provide my http service that has the following implementation:

```
def start[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect: ContextShift: Sync: Timer]: HttpApp[F] =
for {

  a <- EnvironmentLoader.db.load[F].map(create_transactor)
  b <- EnvironmentLoader.cors.load[F].map(origin)
       http = Logger.httpApp(true, true)(CORS(UserRoutes(UserProgram(LiveUserQuery.make(a))).routes, b).orNotFound)
} yield http
```

The `start` method should return `HttpApp[F]` but unfortunately the `for` block returns `F[Http[F]]`. However at the end the `F` will be an `IO` type.

Here is the definition of `HttpApp[F]`:

```
type Http[F[_], G[_]] = Kleisli[F, Request[G], Response[G]]
```

The both `EnvironmentLoader.db.load[F].map(create_transactor)` and `EnvironmentLoader.cors.load[F].map(origin)` is in the context of `F` and they load environment variables. For loading environment variables, I use the library https://cir.is/.

I know, it is not possible to get `Http[F]` out of the context `F`. Do I have here to restructure the code to make it work?

**Update**

One possible workaround would be:

```
class UserSvcServlet
    extends AsyncHttp4sServlet[IO](
      service = UserSvcServer.start[IO].unsafeRunSync(),
      servletIo = BlockingServletIo(4096, Blocker.liftExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())),
      serviceErrorHandler = DefaultServiceErrorHandler
    )
```

It is ugly but it works.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to.

When you have `F[Http[F]]` you are supposed to compose it into your IO program:

```
for {
  dep1 <- createDependency1
  dep1 <- createDependency2
  http <- createHttp // : F[HttpApp[F]] = F[Request[F] => F[Response[F]]]
                     // or "use side effects to create a function that
                     // will take side-effecting request to create
                     // recipe for side-effecting response" (e.g.
                     // reading from stream to server and returning
                     // a stream from server)
  dep4 =  needHttp(http)
  ...
} yield ...
```

In your code a change from `F[HttpApp[F]]` to `HttpApp[F]` seems to literally require just changing:

```
http = ...
```

into

```
http <- ...
```

which kind of suggest, that you are not paying enough attention to what your code does.

Comment: I can not now, because `UserSvcServlet` expects `HttpApp[F]` and I can not call the class within the `for` block.

Comment: Then move out its initialization of outside and pass something that is already initialized..

Comment: I have forgot to mention, `class UserSvcServlet` is the end of the world. Can be compare with https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/ioapp.html. The app will run on Jetty.

Comment: It can not be moved to outside.